# DateTime filter

Tags: c#, optimization, linq, datetime

I have been trying to optimize the filtering process of a `Collection<Alert>` based on the `DateTime GeneratedOn` property of `Alert` class.

Below is the code block which filters the `List` by taking in `From Date` and `To Date`.

```
if (this.Alerts != null)
        {
            var fromDt = Convert.ToDateTime(this.FromDateAlert.ToShortDateString() + " " + this.FromTimeAlert.ToLongTimeString());
            var toDt = Convert.ToDateTime(this.ToDateAlert.ToShortDateString() + " " + this.ToTimeAlert.ToLongTimeString());

            if (fromDt > toDt)
            {
                Messages.InfoMessage("FromDate cannot be greater than ToDate", "Alert"); return;
            }
            this.IsBusy = true;
            var filteredAlerts = this.Alerts.Where(a => (DateTime.Parse(a.Created) >= fromDt) && (DateTime.Parse(a.Created) <= toDt));              
            this.PagedAlerts = new PagedCollectionView(filteredAlerts);
            this.IsBusy = false;
        }
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You mean you're trying to make this code faster? Did profiling tell you this code is really a bottleneck in your application?

Comment: But my primary advice would be to try to avoid strings for representing dates and times as much as possible. Certainly don't use them to combine a date with a time, that will be slow and unreliable.

Comment: I want a very precise filtering that can even filter out records based on time, that's why I combined the Date and Time, by converting it to ToShortDateString() and ToLongTimeString().

Comment: Yeah, but I don't see any reason why you would use strings for that. You should work only with the `DateTime`s directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why are you storing `FromDate` and `FromTime` seperately to begin with?**

Instead of storing using four properties, use only two, storing both Date and TimeOfDay inside them:

```
public DateTime FromAlert { get; private set; }
public DateTime ToAlert { get; private set; }
```

In the following code:

```
var fromDt = Convert.ToDateTime(this.FromDateAlert.ToShortDateString() + " " + this.FromTimeAlert.ToLongTimeString());
var toDt = Convert.ToDateTime(this.ToDateAlert.ToShortDateString() + " " + this.ToTimeAlert.ToLongTimeString());
```

You are converting multiple DateTime values to strings in order to parse them again *(this should immediately raise a red flag)*. When you use the DateTime fields like they were meant to (i.e. containing both Date and TimeOfDay), you can get rid of these redundant conversions:

```
if (FromAlert > ToAlert)
{
    Messages.InfoMessage("FromDate cannot be greater than ToDate", "Alert"); 
    return; //always put this on a separate line!!
}
```

> I have been trying to optimize the filtering process of a Collection based on the DateTime
>   GeneratedOn property of Alert class.

And why are you parsing the string `Alert.Created` if you already have a `DateTime Alert.GeneratedOn`? Just use it:

```
var filteredAlerts = Alerts.Where(a => a.GeneratedOn >= fromDt && a.GeneratedOn <= toDt);
```

Comment: Hi @codesparkle thanks for your valuable post. For some strange and anonymous reason I had been getting the Alert's CreatedOn prop as a string. So I went up to that guy who was associated with this retrieving Alerts of a system from system center operations manager and asked him why can't you just get CreatedOn as DateTime instead of a string so he changed its type to DateTime. The whole mess of multiple conversions and parsing was 'cause of the CreatedOn prop being a string type.